# Highcharts event redraw/load with reflow, and Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I'm using Angular Highcharts, although I don't think it makes a lot of difference in this case. I'm using a responsive design, and the chart appears before it "figures out" the size of the parent element. Not a problem, except triggering reflow doesn't appear to work in the callback of redraw or load.

Here is the basic code:

```
events: {
    redraw: function(event) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('highchartsng.reflow');
    }
}
```

If I use "load" instead of redraw, it works even worse as it triggers first and doesn't recognize the highcharts object at all.

Comment: Have you tried to call [setSize](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setSize) function instead of reflow?

Comment: It's a responsive site design, plus the redraw event seems to fire before the rendering actually occurs.

Comment: I tried this by getting the width of the parent element, unfortunately setting width does not account for the labels on the right side.

Comment: It doesn't appear setSize is available as a function within "this" when using redraw either.

Answer (score 0):

That's what MutationObserver is for. Available in IE11, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver. You need to inject $element service into controller which semi-breaks DOM/controller separation, but I feel that this is a fundamental exception (ie. flaw) in angularjs. Since hide/show is async, we need on-show callback, that angularjs & angular-bootstrap-tab do not provide. It also requires that u know which specific DOM element u want to observe. I used following code for angularjs controller to trigger Highcharts chart reflow on-show.

```
const myObserver = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    const isVisible = $element.is(':visible') // Requires jquery
    if (!_.isEqual(isVisible, $element._prevIsVisible)) { // Lodash
        if (isVisible) {
            $scope.$broadcast('onReflowChart')
        }
        $element._prevIsVisible = isVisible
    }
})
myObserver.observe($element[0], {
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: ['class']
})
```